# How to run python script in remote machine opened through putty

Tags: python, ssh, putty

I have a python program which I run in the python shell. Now I open putty with a host name through ssh connection. I login with username and password. Now my problem is that my python program has to run in this remote server that I have opened through putty. The output files that this python program generates has to be stored in the remote server only. Should I copy my python script to the remote server and install python in the remote server to run my script? Or is there any other way this can be done? How to install specific python modules in the remote server?

Comment: yes, copy your script there and run it with the python therein. Should be installed in most Unixy servers by name `python` or `python2` for Python 2, and `python3` for Python 3...

Comment: There _are_ other ways that it can be done (e.g., you could set up a virtual  filesystem on the server on top of, say, SFTP back to your client, so your local files are available to the server). But @AnttiHaapala's suggestion is by far the easiest way.

Comment: If the "program has to run on the remote server" then I take it that it **has to run** on the remote server.

Comment: For installing python on the remote server, should the python.exe file has to be copied to the remote server and has to be run there?

Comment: Linux and Unix distributions come preinstalled with Python. Is the server Windows? In that case, you must install using a remote desktop connection or manually log on to install Python.

Comment: How do I know what is the OS in the remote server? Is there some command for that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to copy your python script to the remote server.

Here is a link on how to [copy files to a remote server using putty](http://www.it.cornell.edu/services/managed_servers/howto/file_transfer/fileputty.cfm).

If you are connecting through putty then your server should be (I think so) Unix/Linux. Exe files won't work there, but the Python should be installed by default.

Type in the shell (command prompt) `uname -a` or `more /etc/issue` to learn what Unix/Linux there is on the remote server.

Navigate to the folder where you copied python script `cd /my/directory/`

Launch the script `python yourscript.py`

Comment: The remote server has a default python 2.7.9. But if I want to use any specific python modules, how should I install them in the remote server?

Comment: That is a job of server administrator to install additional modules. You will need root's access to that server in order to install software. Depending on distro you will use `dpkg`, `yum` or `dnf` (or other) utility to find and install software from repositories. Can't help much without knowing distro and modules.

Comment: Actually you can have specific modules without having root access. _Virtualenv_ is what you are looking for and it might be already installed on the remote server. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv